How do I create a ButtonStyle with a a larger image?
I’m trying to create a ButtonStyle for an application. I can find plenty of examples, but I can’t get much actual detail.
Here is a simple example:
struct SpecialButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold))
            .imageScale(.large)
    }
}

The .imageScale() value appears to be limited to one of three sizes, but the .large value is still smaller that I would have liked, and I would have liked a larger image size.
Is there a way to do this in a ButtonStyle?

Are you using a symbol image or your custom image? For symbol images, changing font should be enough. For your own images, you are responsible for creating an image file that is appropriately sized.

@Sweeper I am using a symbol image. However, if I change the font, that would also change the text size, which I’m trying to avoid. I want the image to be larger, relative to the text.

I see. How about adding an extra optional argument to your button style to allow the caller to provide the image there?

You can define a LabelStyle to style the label the way you want it:
struct SpecialLabel: LabelStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.icon
                .font(.largeTitle)
            configuration.title
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold))
        }
    }
}

Of course, you could use a VStack if preferred.
Then use the special label style inside your custom ButtonStyle:
struct SpecialButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .labelStyle(SpecialLabel())
    }
}

Example use:
Button("Delete", systemImage: "trash") {}
    .buttonStyle(SpecialButton())



It’s strange that ButtonStyle doesn’t have configuration.icon, so this does the job nicely.
